# Do not understand a concept in analysis of open-address hashing

Tags: hash, hashing

I am reading the "Introduction to Algorithms" by Thomas Cormen et al. Particularly the theorem which says that given an open-address hash table with load factor α=n/m<1, the expected number of probes in an unsuccessful search is at most 1/(1−α), assuming uniform hashing.

In the proof they are saying -

$p_i$ = It is the probability of *exactly* i probes where we are finding all of the slots to be occupied. i is 0,1,2,…

$q_i$ = It is the probability of *at least* i probes where we are finding all of the slots to be occupied. i is 0,1,2,…

Then it says -

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty i\,p_i\, = \sum_{i=1}^\infty q_i$$

How it is so?

Answer (score 2):

For any $i$, $q_i = p_i + p_{i+1} + p_{i+2} + \dots$.  Now look at $\sum_{i\geq 1}q_i$ and how many times each $p_i$ occurs.  $p_1$ occurs only in $q_1$; $p_2$ occurs in $q_1$ and $q_2$; and, in general, $p_i$ occurs only in $q_1,\dots, q_i$.  In other words, each $p_i$ occurs $i$ times in the sum of the $q_i$s.